# Idiom that says "He thinks one thing and says the other"

Tags: idioms, phrases

I speak Hebrew, and here we have a saying:

> Thinks one thing and says the other.

It means that he is a hypocrite. I looked all over the internet to find a similar idiom in English and came up short.

I think maybe "two faced" is a way of expressing a hypocrite, but I wanted to check if there would be any more idiom with the same meaning.

Sorry for my poor English, and thanks for your help!

Comment: I googled for "duplicity idioms" and found **[this](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/duplicity/synonyms/idiom)**. "Double dealing" looks nice. A related question: **[What is an idiom/slang for “someone who pretends to be good when they're not”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42404/what-is-an-idiom-slang-for-someone-who-pretends-to-be-good-when-theyre-not)**

Comment: In English, a hypocrite is someone that does or believes the things that they criticize other people for doing/believing - is that the same nuance that you're looking for? Thinking one thing and saying something else seems more like duplicity as @CopperKettle mentioned or insincerity.

Comment: There's also "speaks with forked tongue", although that implies actual bad will and not just casual hypocrisy, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

That is also an idiom in English, although "...says one thing and does another" is a much more common phrase.

"Two-faced" means that the person will show a different attitude or view when speaking to different people.